# How Does Nginx reads an input?

Tags: html, nginx

I am really noob in Web Development and I would like to know how Nginx would read an input from the user using a simple html form (I am not using PHP or ASP in this stage).

I have this on my html:

```
<form name="input" action="" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the server to do with that information once it has read it?

Comment: You can use [HttpFormInputModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFormInputModule) but what will you do after?

Comment: I would like to redirect the user depending who the user is, I don't know if I am doing the right way, it is just to test some network issues, so I don't need to design a full and complete page. But I am completely open to better ways.

Comment: Since it's GET request, value will be available in `$arg_input` variable in nginx. But you really should read manuals.